# How to root this device? RK3188

Tags: rooting, charging, connection-issues, android-mini-pc

I am attempting to root at RK3188 Mini PC I bought from amazon.
I believe I have found the drivers, but cannot figure out how to connect a USB cable to the device to connect to my PC to root.

Please see pictures below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgauW.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLxA9.jpg

As you can see the device has a:
HDMI port,
Charging port,
USB port,
Audio port,

The device takes 2 Amps to power, through the charging port.  I could try connecting a microUSB (?) to usb cable to the PC, but I believe it will not be enough to power the device as USB ports only supply up to 500mA.  I could also try a USB A to A cable, but I also fear damaging both devices.

Any suggests appreciated!
Thank you!

---

Update
Used the micro USB to USB adapter and found the device powered on from a computer USB port.  Still confused as the device needs 2A to operate.

Comment: @Sid we allow one "How to root" question per device. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @DanHulme sowie. my bad.

Comment: any body? should I try and word this question differently?

Comment: Use a self powered usb hub that's capable of delivering 2 amps. Else, you may solder your own USB Y-Cable (or use one of those HDD-Y cables with a micro-USB converter) and provide the power by an external 2A capable wall charger.